# iMacros | reading specific line in file

Tags: imacros

currently I'm reading from file line by line from line 1 to line 10.
Now I need to read in every iteration a specific line too which is 15.
So for example:
Iteration 1: read line 1 ... read line 15
Iteration 2: read line 2 ... read line 15
.
.
Iteration 10: read line 10 ... read line 15
END OF LOOP, OPERATION END.

I don't understand how to read that specific line from the same file(I don't care even reading from a different file but I don't think it's possible to read from multiple files)

Comment: Well, simply hard-code your Row_15 instead of using the '!LOOP' Var, no Script posted, so it's a bit difficult to guess what you are doing... - And you can also use as many DataSources as you like in one same Script, but that wouldn't add any Benefit in your Case, I would think...

Answer (score 0):

Use !DATASOURCE_LINE

```
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
PROMPT {{!DATASOURCE_LINE}}
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 15
PROMPT {{!DATASOURCE_LINE}}
```

To learn more, see [example](http://www.imacros.org/primery-makrosov/ispolzovaniedatasourceline)